# Name of this variegated plant

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

Anyone know the name of this variegated plant. I purchased it a month ago from nursery , i week ago it was at home in low light now i put it in bright indirect sunlight.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Peperomia obtusifolia with variegated leaves, image here https://exoticflora.in/products/peperomia-variegated-indoor-plants.

It does not appreciate direct sunlight, preferring medium to bright daylight, and should be kept at roughly 60-70 degrees F. It also needs high air humidity, so this plant is often used in terrariums, or grouped with other plants to increase the humidity around it. Water only when the surface of the compost feels dry to the touch, then water well, emptying out any excess from the outer pot or tray 30 minutes afterwards. I hope your plant is in a pot with a drainage hole - it looks from the image that its planted straight into a china pot... More detailed care instructions here https://www.houseplant411.com/houseplant/how-to-grow-a-peperomia-plant-care-guide

Comment: Thanks @bamboo , It is potted in Plastic pot with three drainage holes, I receives only 30 mins of direct sunlight that also in evening. And i mist it every hour , Now as it's winter season i water it every 2 weeks.

Comment: Re watering - don't stick to a schedule of giving water, just use a schedule to check it by touching the soil with your finger to determine how damp it is or isn't  - and pick up the pot, it gets much lighter when it needs watering. That way, you don't end up over  or under watering... You may also  need to move it elsewhere during summer if it gets more sun then.

Comment: Yes doing the same thing , as i am using peat moss + compost + perlite as a medium it becomes light weight which signals it needs watering. After watering it has weight everyday im checking it. But i know it will retain moisture for next 10 days,